# one .h multiple .m files

Tags: objective-c

Good evening, i need to know how can i have one .h file that defines my class and multiple .m files for the same class! the project is big and i am loosing it:S. Can you please paste a simple example?

Sincerely

L_Sonic

Comment: Your classes are quite large if they're that unmanageable. You might consider breaking them up into smaller classes. Classes will typically go from a couple hundred to about a thousand or so lines, in my experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Categories:

Foo.h

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
// all your properties
// all your public methods
@end
```

Foo.m

```
#import "Foo-Bar.h"
@implementation Foo
// public method implementation
@end
```

Foo-Bar.h

```
#import "Foo.h"
@interface Foo (Bar)
// private method interfaces
@end
```

Foo-Bar.m

```
#import "Foo-Bar.h"
@implementation Foo (Bar)
// private method implementation
@end
```

In your implementation for Foo, you can now access any of the methods defined in `Foo (Bar)`

Keep in mind that all your properties and ivars must be defined in Foo

You can continue to do this eg. `Foo (Duck)`

Another option is to put

```
#pragma mark - Some title
```

in your code.  You can then use the Jump bar (at the top of the file editor) to group your methods

Comment: Thank you for your response... it is a actually a bit late for this, i figured everything out by now...  :)

Comment: Thanks Zeophlite.  I moved my ~200 lines of UISwipeGestureRecognizer code out of the main viewController code this way.  It doesn't matter that the lines were mostly "pretty" formatting of UIView animation blocks... getting well-tested and largely static code out of the main body of the view controller code is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your classes are too big. Make them smaller.

Comment: Agreed.  You are building a [God object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

Comment: Yes i could but the problem is that the class i want to break is a view controller which is responsible for my games logic i cannot break no more!

Comment: Perhaps you should work with someone else to determine how best to break out the logic in your view controller. "It's impossible" is the wrong answer.